# WCF RIA Services & Silverlight: Custom Exception Messages + Load operation failed for x

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

So on the server I send back custom exception messages, meant to be displayed to the user (think "Bad Username/Password", "Account has been locked out" etc.)

However, when I view the Exception message in silverlight it is prefixed with "Load operation failed for x."  I was thinking that Exception.InnerException would be a good place to put the original Exception, but I guess the RIA team didn't agree.

Is there a way to get my original exception message? Sure, I could write a quick regex to parse it out, but that feels dirty... Is that my only option?

Answer (score 0):

I read about a solution that may work for you. I have yet to implement it myself though.

http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/02/10/make-use-of-wcf-faultcontracts-in-silverlight-clients/

Comment: This is about WCF FaultExceptions, not Ria Services.

Comment: @Pemankh it should still be appicable as ria uses wcf under the hood